# Compute the integral of $e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, solution-verification

I am working on a problem in my past Qual.

"Prove that $e^{-x}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and compute the integral."

Here is my solution: $e^{-x}$ is continuous, hence measurable. We can use the monotone convergence theorem
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} = \int_0^n \lim(e^{-x}\chi_{[0,n]})=\lim \int_0^n(e^{-x})=1<\infty$$
So it is Lebesgue integrable.

This solution seems too short and direct. So I doubt that it is wrong.

Comment: This is fine. No problem at all with the proof.

Comment: Perhaps also mention that the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^n e^{-x}\;dx$ is the same as the Riemann integral.

Comment: I also doubt that it is wrong (that is to say, I think it is correct)

Comment: The first $=$ is wrong.

Comment: zhw what do you mean? the convergence here is pointwise, right?

Comment: He means your bounds on the integral are wrong.